# Rails: around_save callback to conditionally trigger an action specific to one attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

My Rails app has events and users. I need to send a message to a user if/when they're added to an event, whether it's a new event being created or an existed one being updated. To avoid messaging them multiple times, I'm considering a design pattern like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  around_save :contact_added_users

  def contact_added_users
    existing_users = self.users
    yield
    added_users = self.users.reject{|u| existing_users.include? u }
    added_users.each { |u| u.contact }
  end
end
```

Is this a sensible approach? I'm not sure how to work this functionality into the conditional callbacks pattern.

Edit: It occurs to me that this won't work as `added_users` will always be empty.

Update: In order to minimize conflicts with existing code, I think I'm going to avoid using callbacks in the model, and instead use an around filter in the controller. Also, that allows me to query the database for the existing users before they're attached to the event object. Something like this (using ActiveAdmin):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  controller do
    around_filter :contact_added_users

    def contact_added_users
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      existing_users = @event.users
      yield
      added_users = @event.users.reject{|u| existing_users.include? u }
      added_users.each { |u| u.contact }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: User can participate to only one event? or more events?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 It's a grossly simplified example. In reality a user could participate in many events, so there's a join model involved.

Comment: Great, and I assume each time you create or edit an event you can add more than one user at a time? right?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 Yes, exactly

Comment: Well, that method looks good to me. Thank you by the way, I was just reading about this callback :) really nice, you get existing users, finish transaction, get the new added users and send them emais. Nice. +1

Comment: @rmagnum2002 The problem is `existing_users` isn't pulled from the database, but from the in-memory event-object, so there's no difference between it at `event.users` after the save.

Comment: added users could be found also by doing `self.users - existing_users`

Comment: @rmagnum2002 Again though, existing_users will contain the same collection of users that was saved to the event, so the subtraction gives an empty set.

Comment: Ivan, how about you take this to the Users model, with ActiveModel::Dirty? "before_save :do_your_magic" AND def do_your_magic { if event_id_changed? blah blah }

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis I like it! Since the real version is a has_many_through, I should probably put the callback in the join-model. Actually, that would reflect the intention of the feature quite well! Thanks!

Comment: @rmagnum2002 After all that, I think database persistance won't be an issue if I move this logic into the controller.

Comment: @ivan see my new edited answer